# MapView only shows correct location after 2nd load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, mkmapview

Im struggling with a `mapview` on my app. When loading the screen with the `mapview` on, the map just opens to the default location for `mapviews`. However, when I return to the previous scren and then launch the map for a 2nd time, the correct location is displayed.

Obviously, this isn't ideal.

Any suggestions please?

My code is:

```
CLLocation *mapLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
[[self map] setCenterCoordinate:[mapLocation coordinate]];
[[self map] setRegion: MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mapLocation coordinate], 1000, 1000)];        
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:[mapLocation coordinate]];
[[self map] addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should post code which loads map view because this code will work well.

Comment: when do you do this? and yeah... show the map view code

Comment: this code is on the mapViewController on viewDidLoad...
Sorry, im still learning. What code should I post??

Answer (score 0):

I set the current location like this:

Location.h:

```
@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;    
MKMapView *worldView;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
IBOutlet UITextField *locationTextField;
}

- (void)findLocation;
- (void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc;
- (IBAction)setMapTyp:(id)sender;

@property MKMapType mapType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *currentDate;

@end
```

Location.m:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);

NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (t < -180) {
    return;
}

[self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
[worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

- (void)findLocation {
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[locationTextField setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm, dd. MMM. yyyy "];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];

MyOwnMapPoint *mp = [[MyOwnMapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord
                                                    title:[locationTextField text]
                                                 subtitle:dateString];
NSLog(@"Die Uhrzeit ist: %@", dateString);
[worldView addAnnotation:mp];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 250, 250);
[worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

//Reset the UI
[locationTextField setText:@""];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[locationTextField setHidden:NO];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Hope its giving you an idea!

Comment: Sorry im quite new to objective c and im not really understanding this.

Comment: try to use `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` to show your location on startup!

Comment: Yeah i see now. I tried an NSLog to make sure it was being called...but it isn't.

Nothing I try works! I still have to press my refresh button, which uses the same code as my loadLocation button.